# pgadmin remotely access postresql service in kubernetes

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, pgadmin, rancher

I launch a pod from rancher and my pgsql daemon is running fine.
Then ingres is set up with a target (pod name) and port 5432
Then use kubectl to start port forwarding

After these steps are completed, I can access the db from within the kubernetes cluster using

```sh
kubectl exec -it pod/<pod_name> -n <ns_name> -- psql -U postgres
```

This ran fine.

Then I tried to connect to the db using pgadmin on my laptop. It always failed with
Unable to connect to server:

```sh
Could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
Is the server running on host "pgsql.kube.xx.yy.com" (###.##.###.##) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I can connect to db from another pod in the k8s cluster.
this works for me in another pod:

```sh
./psql --host <pod.ip> -U postgres -d metastore -p 5432
```

Ingress config:

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    field.cattle.io/creatorId: u-abcdefg
    field.cattle.io/ingressState: '{"c######M=":"p#####q:sslcerts","c#####g==":"statefulset:pgsql-###:pgsql-####"}'
    field.cattle.io/publicEndpoints: '[{"addresses":["##.##.##.##"],"port":443,"protocol":"HTTPS","serviceName":"pgsql-###:ingress-5###","ingressName":"pgsql-###:posgres-ingres","hostname":"pgsql-##.kube.##.###.###s","allNodes":true}]'
  creationTimestamp: "2021-11-10T19:01:30Z"
  generation: 5
  labels:
    cattle.io/creator: norman
  name: posgres-ingres
  namespace: pgsql-###
  resourceVersion: "343048085"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/pgsql-###/ingresses/posgres-ingres
  uid: 10###-###-########-######
spec:
  rules:
  - host: pgsql-##.kube.##.##.##
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: ingress-########
          servicePort: 5432
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - pgsql-###.kube.##.##.###
    secretName: sslcerts
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: ##.##.##.##
    - ip: ##.##.##.##
    - ip: ###.###.###.###
    - ip: ###.###.###.###
```

Your suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#what-is-ingress):

> An Ingress does not expose arbitrary ports or protocols. Exposing services other than HTTP and HTTPS to the internet typically uses a service of type [Service.Type=NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-nodeport) or [Service.Type=LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer).

PostgreSQL is a SQL database and typically doesn't use http as protocol. From the Postgres [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/protocol.html).

> PostgreSQL uses a message-based protocol for communication between frontends and backends (clients and servers). The protocol is supported over TCP/IP and also over Unix-domain sockets.